# Игнорирование стилей в Android

Tags: android

При применении стилей многие их параметры почему-то игнорируются.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/regionColumn"
android:layout_width="170dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/regionHeader"
   style="@style/AppTheme.TableHeaderTextView"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:text="@string/region" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Например, при добавлении в такой контейнер TextView со стилем, игнорируются все отступы и высота. 
Сам стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TableTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">8pt</item>        
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">80dp</item>
</style>
```

Почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему?

P.S. `TableHeaderTextView` - это заголовок столбца. `TableTextView` - обычная ячейка таблицы.

Comment: По всей видимости опечатались - TableHeaderTextView и TableTextView

Comment: Нет. TableHeaderTextView - это заголовок столбца. TableTextView - обычная ячейка таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам.

Нужно отступы указывать в `LayoutParams`, иначе они игнорируются.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(5, 20, 20, 30);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Размеры, отступы и всё что есть в `LayoutParams` - не являются "стильными" атрибутами и не могут применяться ко всем виджетам разом. Поэтому их нужно задавать индивидуально: в разметке (в тэге `<TextView>` в данном примере) или программно, как сделали Вы.